# comfortable way to use unicode characters in a ggplot graph

Tags: r, unicode, ggplot2

Is there a good practice to insert unicode characters in a ggplot title and also save it as pdf?

I am struggling with expression, paste and sprintf to get a nice title...

So, what works is

```
ggtitle(expression(paste('5', mu, 'g')))
```

This will print an ugly greek mu. By ugly I mean a different font, but overall, it will be printed as pdf without problems. But the problems start, if you want to have new lines in the title. Or maybe I didn't found a solution for this.

My preferred solution would be to use sprintf with the unicode number, so for example

```
ggtitle(sprintf('5\u03BCg'))
```

It shows a nice result on the screen but it is not possible to save as pdf with ggsave. PNG works fine, but I would like to use the pdf save option.

Is there a possibility to plot the unicode characters with ggsave? I read about the cairo_pdf device, but this messes up the fonts and I can not save the plot properly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:**
[Example PDF](http://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/madejung/test.pdf)

I just uploaded an example PDF... So maybe my problem is somewhere else...

Comment: I tried with `ggsave(file="newfile.pdf", device=cairo_pdf)`, couldn't find much difference between the version on console and the one saved as pdf.

Comment: It might be better if you provide some reproducible example so that others can check.

Comment: I uploaded an example pdf... And it looks like, the fonts will not get embedded or something... I would really love to fix this problem and use unicode characters in the future!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value)) 
p <- p + geom_line()
p + ggtitle(sprintf('5\u03BCg'))
library(Cairo)
ggsave("newfile.pdf", device=cairo_pdf)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42) 
df <- data.frame(date = 1:10 , value = cumsum(runif(10 , max = 10)) )
```

Comment: I didn't load the Cairo library, but my problem still exists... [link](http://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/madejung/newfile.pdf) Maybe I should mention, I use a MAC sysem

Comment: @user7601 I don't have that problem.  I wish I could share my pdf.  Here, I can upload only image files.  I am using `linux mint 17` with `R 3.1.2`

Comment: Wow, I used `R 3.1.0`... It seems to be fixed in `R 3.1.2`... So no longer messing with unnicode characters in the plots!!! Thanks a lot akrun!

Answer (score 4):

Using the `emojifont` package fixes this issue for me.

```
library(emojifont)
```

Comment: This works seamlessly without worrying about version numbers, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing the tricks to have Unicode characters properly displayed on PDF files. I am currently running R-4.0.5 for Windows.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(png)

#--- The trick to get unicode characters being printed on pdf files:
#--- 1. Create a temporary file, say "temp.png"
#--- 2. Create the pdf file using pdf() or cairo_pdf(), say "UnicodeToPDF.pdf"
#--- 3. Combine the use of grid.arrange (from gridExtra), rasterGrob (from grid), and readPNG (from png) to insert the
#       temp.png file into the UnicodeToPDF.pdf file
test.plot = ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(x=1, y=1), aes(x,y), shape = "\u2191", size=3.5) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(x=2, y=2), aes(x,y), shape = "\u2020", size=3.5) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(x=1.2, y=1.2), aes(x,y), shape = -10122, size=3.5, color="#FF7F00") +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(x=1.4, y=1.4), aes(x,y), shape = -129322, size=3.5, color="#FB9A99") +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(x=1.7, y=1.7), aes(x,y), shape = -128515, size=5, color="#1F78B4") +
  ggtitle(sprintf('5\u03BCg'))

ggsave("temp.png", plot = test.plot, width = 80, height = 80, units = "mm")
#--- Refer to http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_index.html to see more unicode character integers

pdf("UnicodeToPDF.pdf")
grid.arrange(
  rasterGrob(
    readPNG(
      "temp.png",
      native=F
    )
  )
)
dev.off()

file.remove("temp.png")
```